Stokes theorem for currents on manifolds with corners
Let $M\subset\mathbb R^N$ be a compact oriented $n$-(sub)manifold with corners and $\omega$ be an $(n-1)$-form on it. The usual statement of Stokes theorem
$$\int_M d\omega=\int_{\partial M}\omega$$
is proven using the fact that the corners have null measure in $\partial M$ and hence do not contribute to the integral. This justifies the definition of $\partial M$ as just the dimension $n-1$ components of the topological version of $\partial M$ which is the disjoint union of manifolds without boundary of dimension $0,1,\dots ,n-1$.
Let $\mathcal D^p(M)$ be the space of $p$-forms on $M$ with the topology induced by the norm $\lVert\omega\rVert=\sum_I \lVert f_I\rVert_\infty$ where $\omega=\sum_{I}f_I dx_I$. We can define a current of degree $p$ as a continuous linear form
\begin{align*}
t:\mathcal D^{n-p}&\to\mathbb C\\
\alpha&\mapsto T(\alpha)=\left<T, \alpha\right>=\int_M T\wedge\alpha.
\end{align*}
And the differential by the tautological-looking yet necessary $\left< dT,\alpha\right>=(-1)^{p+1}\left<T, d\alpha\right>$. For $p=n$ we likewise define $\int_M T=\int_M T\wedge 1=\left<T, 1\right>$ where $1$ is the $0$-form identified to the smooth function which is constant and equal to $1$. Now I want to have Stokes theorem for forms on $M$, that is: Given an $(n-1)$-current $T$ on $M$ we have
$$\int_M dT=\int_{\partial M}T$$
for an appropriate definition of $\partial M$. This time we can't ignore the corners like we did for integration of smooth forms because null-measure sets do contribute to the integral. It seems nontrivial to figure out what's the correct orientation for the components of $\partial M$ with dimension less than $n-1$. What is the correct definition of $\partial M$, especially the orientation of each component? I'd love to have an answer or a reference to more information about currents and manifolds with corners.
(I think all of this would be also possible without the assumption that $M$ is compact and a submanifold of euclidean space but the statements might be longer.)

Have you looked at standard resources on geometric measure theory? The gentlest is by Frank Morgan. The harshest is Federer’s classic.

@TedShifrin I have not since I'm largely not aware of geometric measure theory.

This question has been largely answered by Huber 2023:
Proposition 6.3: Let $X$ be a definable $C^p$-manifold with corners for $2\leq p<\infty$. Let $G\subset X$ be a pseudo-oriented compact definable subset of dimension $d$ and $\omega$ a $(d-1)$-form of class $C^1$ in a neighborhood of $G$. Then there's a formal $\mathbb Z$-linear combination $\Sigma$ of pseudo-oriented compact definable subsets of $G$ of dimension $d-1$ such that
$$\int_G d\omega=\int_{\Sigma}\omega.$$
See the paper for all the definitions. I haven't completely understood it to be honest, but I know she does answer the crux of my question which was how to orient the boundary of a manifold with corners. The answer being to do a triangulation procedure and orient it as a manifold with corners of one dimension lower. The paper cites a paper by Antoine Julia and his PhD thesis which do something for currents with singularities which is also worthwhile to read.
